# "Missing __block type specifier" compilation error after refactoring code but ok before refactor

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have some code that downloads an image and assigns it within a block. The code currently works however I want to refactor it into a separate method, however after the refactoring I get a compilation error.

This is the original code which compiles and runs with the downloaded image being assigned successfully:

```
- (void) someMethod
{
   …
   MyObject* object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
   [self.objects addObject: object];

   NSString* graphRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",  @"https://graph.facebook.com/",
                              fbid,
                              @"/picture?type=square"];
    FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];
    [fbRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *theError)
     {
         NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *dict = (NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *) result;
         if (dict)
         {
             NSString* urlAsString = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
             if ([urlAsString length] > 0)
             {
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlAsString];
                 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                 object.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

If I refactor it to the following then I get a compilation error

```
- (void) someMethod
{
   …
   MyObject* object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
   [self.objects addObject: object];
   [self fetchFbImage: object.image forFbid:fbid];
}


- (void) fetchFbImage:(UIImage*) targetImage forFbid:(NSString*) fbid
{
    NSString* graphRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",  @"https://graph.facebook.com/",
                              fbid,
                              @"/picture?type=square"];
    FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];
    [fbRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *theError)
     {
         NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *dict = (NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *) result;
         if (dict)
         {
             NSString* urlAsString = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
             if ([urlAsString length] > 0)
             {
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlAsString];
                 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                 targetImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

The compilation error is the line assigning into targetImage, "Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)".

Where should I add the __block type specifier? And why is there an issue after the refactoring but not before?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused over how parameters work in Objective-C.

In your original code you have:

```
MyObject* object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

which declares `object` as a local variable of the method. Then within the block you write:

```
object.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

So your block references the local variable `object` and (as you have no `__block` attribute on the declaration) the block gets a *constant* copy of the contents of variable. This is fine because you are not changing what is in `object`, which is a reference to your `MyObject` instance, but are calling a method on that instance which changes the internal state of that instance.[*]

Now let's look at your refactoring. You remove a chunk of your `someMethod`'s code and place it in a new method `fetchFbImage`. In `someMethod` you call `fetchFbImage`:

```
[self fetchFbImage:object.image forFbid:fbid];
```

This passes the *current value* of `object.image` to the method it **does not** pass the property in such a way that it can be assigned to in `fetchFbImage`. The type of the argument `targetImage` is `UIImage *` - a reference to an `UIImage` - it is not "a property of type `UIImage *`" - you cannot have arguments of such a type, properties cannot be passed around only their values or reference to objects which have properties.

When a method is called each parameter is effectively a local variable which is initialised to the argument value passed, so the above method call effectively performs:

```
UIImage *targetImage = object.image;
```

where `targetImage` is a local variable in the scope of `fetchFbImage` and `object` is the local variable in the scope of `someMethod`.

Now within the block inside of `fetchFbImage` you write:

```
targetImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

This is wrong for two reasons:

1. You cannot assign to `targetImage` within the block. This is a local variable belonging to `fetchFbImage`, that local variable is not attributed with `__block`, and so the block has a constant copy of it - and you cannot assign to constants. This is why the compiler issues the error message.
2. However your issue is bigger than this, you are assuming that an assignment to `fetchFbImage`'s local variable `targetImage` will some how invoke the property `object.image` - and there is no way it can do that. `targetImage` is just a local variable which was initialised with the *value* of `object.image` by the method call.

The only way to fix this is to pass `fetchFbImage` a reference to your `MyObject` instance and then within the block inside of `fetchFbImage` to assign to the `image` property of that object just as your pre-refectored code did.

So your code will look something like:

```
- (void) fetchFbImage:(MyObject *)targetObject forFbid:(NSString *)fbid
{
   ...
   targetObject.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
   ...
}

...

[self fetchFbImage:object forFbid:fbid];
```

HTH

**Addendum**

Seeing your comment on another answer it appears you would like `fetchFbImage` to have no knowledge of `MyObject` and be able to fetch images regardless of where they will be referenced from.

A simple way to do this is to follow the same design you have for `FBRequest` - use a completion handler. For convenience define a type for the completion block:

```
typedef void (^ImageConsumer)(NSImage *image);
```

Now define your method to take one of these:

```
- (void) fetchFbImageForFbid:(NSString *)fbid completionHandler:(ImageConsumer)handler
```

In your block within `fetchFbImageForFbid` pass the image to the handler:

```
handler([UIImage imageWithData:data]);
```

And in the call in `someMethod` pass a block which assigns the value to your property:

```
[self fetchFbImageForFbid:fbid
        completionHandler:^(NSImage *image) { object.image = image; }
];
```

---

[*] If this is confusing think of the reference as the address of a house. The address is constant, how many people are in the house is not. You can tell someone "go to this address, there is a great party on" - the contents ("state") of the house changes, its address does not.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

in your first method (with out refactoring), you can set the image to object becuase you have reference to the object, so you did

```
object.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

But after refactoring , you can't set image in the way you are doing,you should send the object also.

```
- (void) someMethod
{
   …
   MyObject* object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
   [self.objects addObject: object];
   [self fetchFbImageForObj:object forFbid:fbid];
}


- (void) fetchFbImageForObject:(MyObject*)object forFbid:(NSString*) fbid
{
    NSString* graphRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",  @"https://graph.facebook.com/",
                              fbid,
                              @"/picture?type=square"];
    FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];
    [fbRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *theError)
     {
         NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *dict = (NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *) result;
         if (dict)
         {
             NSString* urlAsString = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
             if ([urlAsString length] > 0)
             {
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlAsString];
                 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                 object.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

try it.If any error or something,comment below.

Comment: Thanks, what's the explanation for that though? Why can the image not be set in this way?

Comment: Yes it compiles, thanks. Can you explain why please.

Comment: The image cant be set because, assigning newly downloaded image to target image would not result in assigning that targetImage to object .   Object.image is pointer to some UIImage object.

Comment: The solution works but has the disadvantage that the method must now have knowledge about the object rather then just the generic UIimage. Is there a way of just passing a UIImage?